# UI Slow to Update *ONLY* If Called In Response To Change Occurring in NSURLSessionUploadTask Completion Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

The app interacts with php scripts on my server. A user can create a booking, and details are written to a database. Subsequently, they can cancel that booking.

Within the app, a booking is an object, responsible for gathering its own details from the server. A booking can also cancel itself (at the user's request) - pressing "the cancel button" in `BookingViewController` calls the booking's `(void)cancelBooking` method, which posts to `bookings-cancel.php` using an NSURLSessionUploadTask with json data rolled from `@{ @"invoiceNumber": self.invoiceNumber }`.

The database is updated, the uploadSession returns new details, and the booking updates itself according. All of this is nicely responsive - up and back in less than a second, consistently.

**The problem** comes when I attempt to update the UI on `BookingViewController` (labels for delivery date and price) using values read from the booking object *after* it has updated itself (within the uploadSession completion block).

BookingViewController is assigned as the booking's delegate. The booking is setup for KVO on its own "price" property. Whenever the price changes, the booking calls a delegate method `priceDidChange:(NSString *)updatedPrice` on `BookingViewController`, triggering an `NSLog` and updates to `deliveryLabel.text` and `priceLabel.text`.

```
- (void)priceDidUpdate:(NSString *)updatedPrice {
    NSLog(@"priceDidUpdate delegate notification - updatedPrice is: %@", updatedPrice);
    [self.deliveryLabel setText:@"N/A"];
    [self.priceLabel setText:updatedPrice];
}
```

Testing has shown that if I update the price directly from the "cancel" button, or with any other explicit command (e.g., self.price = @"123.45") within the `cancelBooking` method *outside of the uploadTask*, then the UI updates just as quickly as the `NSLog` is written out (i.e., near instantaneously).

However, *if the price is updated within the uploadTask completion block*, the NSLog will write out just as responsively **but the updates to `deliveryLabel.text` and priceLabel.text are very slow to occur** - the delay varies between 5 and 12 seconds, approximately.

I've got `NSLogs` all over the place, and am confident this is not merely about a delay getting the updated value to or from the booking object. Easily twenty times already I have seen "`priceDidUpdate delegate notification` - updatedPrice is: 0.00" (the updated price), then counted to 10 before `self.priceLabel.text` is actually set to `@"0.00"`. Totally stumped.

In case it matters, the `NSURLSession` is configured using `ephemeralSessionConfiguration` with no adjustments.

Is there any reason why the UI updates in `BookingViewController` should take longer to occur based on whether or not the call to `priceDidChange` comes from inside or outside the uploadTask completion block?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you're updating the UI on the MAIN THREAD...

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I'd looked into that, and mucked about with a couple GCD tutorials, but... the UI updates are always triggered from within priceDidChange - the only difference is where priceDidChange is being called from: inside or outside the uploadTask completion block. Am I wrong to believe this should rule out which thread is being used to call the UI updates?

Comment: without diving into your code or trying to understand what you're trying to do or even trying to figure what code executes where - this can be easily solved by wrapping your label updates inside a dispatch_a/sync block that runs on the main queue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use main queue to update the UI. Use following code:

```
- (void)priceDidUpdate:(NSString *)updatedPrice 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^()
    {
            //Add method, task you want perform on mainQueue
            //Control UIView, IBOutlet all here
            NSLog(@"priceDidUpdate delegate notification - updatedPrice is: %@", updatedPrice);
            [self.deliveryLabel setText:@"N/A"];
            [self.priceLabel setText:updatedPrice];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, N J! Worked like a charm. In my struggles I had indeed wound up digging into GCD, but it was just too foreign - the answer looks like something I tried, except that it actually works! :-)

FWIW, I'm a first-time caller, long-time listener. SO FTW. Thanks, again!